# How to Interchange and update the order of rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update, row

I have a table called Device and now i  need interchange the order of devid  row for devid 5 and devid 6 .

**CurrentTable**

```
PID DEVID  INID EVTYPEID EVID   ALID    PARMID TEXTID  InputName  Input2Name
1   1       0     30      0    100102      0    14     998-TCR1     998-EMG1
1   2       0     30      0    100103      0    15     998-FR       998-TCR2
9   3       0     30      0    100113      0    25     998-TCR2     998-EMG2
0   4       2     30      0    100114      0    26     998-FR        NULL
8   5      18     4      53    100114      0    0      998-Sg op   998-Sg cl
4   6      17     4      53    1000114     0    0       SG_PB       RA_PB
```

**Expected Result**

```
PID DEVID  INID EVTYPEID EVID   ALID    PARMID TEXTID  InputName  Input2Name
1   1       0     30      0    100102      0    14     998-TCR1     998-EMG1
1   2       0     30      0    100103      0    15     998-FR       998-TCR2
9   3       0     30      0    100113      0    25     998-TCR2     998-EMG2
0   4       2     30      0    100114      0    26     998-FR        NULL
4   6      17     4      53    1000114     0    0       SG_PB       RA_PB
8   5      18     4      53    100114      0    0      998-Sg op   998-Sg cl
```

> I do have 150 column in my table and PID and RID are Primary keys

Comment: Why not use ORDER BY? Or sort in the presentation layer? It's not a great practice to use the table ID as the ordering system. Or is DEVID a column used strictly for ordering?

Comment: is it just 5 and 6 being swapped, or is this an ongoing thing for many lines?

Comment: There is another table poitning here  at column devid  . so i want to make this in same order

Comment: @Twelfth . only for 5 and  6

Comment: an odd one time request then.  If it goes further than a one-shot, considering adding an 'order_number' column to the table thats used entirely to determine ordering.  Possible that the display tool you are using will try to sort the data itself regardless of what SQL returns.

Comment: @Twelfth , its not possible here really , good point though ..

Comment: @Twelfth , can we  update it using row number function ?

Comment: er...share your update script?   normally don't update by order... update table row = newvalue where id = 5       not sure if you can update by rownumber = 5.  Order is really only relevant during selects, not updates

Answer (score 0):

your current select statement plus:

```
Order by case when DEVID = 6 then 5
when DEVID = 6 then 6
else Devid
end
```

Not a pretty solution but answers the question.

Comment: ?  you update based on rowIDs and not some order.  what do you mean by you need to update a column in order?  Feel silly now, I told Gordon linoff this was an ordering question not updating.

Comment: I updated the Title . What i really want is to update the table by interchanging rows, maybe i am making it complicated or too silly. bear with me

Comment: @coffemug - I've got it now...you are viewing a database as if it's a spreadsheet, and it's not.  Rows don't have an ordering when stored in a database, they have an ordering when you select and return them.  You update id 5, you don't update row 5.  Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I have another table which when select devid6 will select the corresponding  inputname from this table. Now its selecting devid5 for devid6 .. hope its clear

Comment: @Twelfth hence my first comment in the original post! Don't use your database IDs for ordering. Make a sequencenumber field or something similar to use for that purpose. Don't change your IDs as it will probably break your entire database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a temp number to switch them around.

```
UPDATE Device SET DEVID=-6 WHERE DEVID=6;
UPDATE Device SET DEVID=6 WHERE DEVID=5;
UPDATE Device SET DEVID=5 WHERE DEVID=-6;
```

If the other table has a foreign key relationship to the DEVID column then it gets a little trickier.  Options:

- You can break the foreign key relationship, make the switch, and then
  put the key back.
- You can create a temp record with DEVID=7 (or
  something else not taken) and use 7 as your placeholder in the query
  above (instead of -6).  Don't forget in that case to delete your
  dummy record when you're done.